# Настройка Netgear M4300-52G (DHCP)

Tags: сеть, ip, dhcp

Помогите пожалуйста. Настроил маршрутизатор так, что на каждый порт назначена выдача своего диапазона IP (10.10.0.0/16). После того, как ПК получает IP, мы заносим его в таблицу ARP (чтобы каждому MAC был присвоен определённый IP).

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы человек, который принесёт на работу свой ноутбук или ПК, при подключении к сети, получал IP отличный от наших. Это необходимо сделать для того, чтобы он не смог видеть наши сетевые ресурсы.

Comment: Вот интересно, как DHCP-сервер должен отличать принесённый извне компьютер от рабочего, подключённого, чтобы тот получил IP для занесения в таблицу статических назначений? А указанный NetGear - вообще коммутатор. *После того, как ПК получает IP, мы заносим его в таблицу ARP (чтобы каждому MAC был присвоен определённый IP).* Вообще-то это (создание статического назначения) надо делать ДО подключения. И не назначать адреса отсутствующим в таблице узлам. Пусть варятся в APIPA...

Comment: Я понял, что я добавляю все ПК в таблицу ARP, а вот про "не назначать адреса отсутствующим в таблице узлам" я немного не понял как это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Очень просто. Вот есть у вас 100 станций. Скажем, DHCP сервер 10.10.0.1. Делаем скоп 10.10.0.2-10.10.0.101, и устанавливаем соответствие MAC-IP для имеющихся 100 станций. Кто бы не подключился к сети - ему свободного адреса нет, будет 169.254.0.0/16. Появился 101-й компьютер - раздвигаем скоп до 10.10.0.2-10.10.0.102, пишем ещё одно назначение...

Comment: А вообще просто установите на портах коммутатора ограничение по MAC - и "левый" компьютер вообще не подключится. Если не догадается сменить MAC...

Comment: Вот это мне конечно нравится, только я точно не найду сейчас где эту настройку найти)))

Comment: *где эту настройку найти* Какую именно?

Comment: Вот эту - "ограничение по MAC"